# Sql commands Syntax Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'

Tags: c#, syntax-error, sqlcommand

I am building a Point of Sales system in C# and I am passing the data from the Interface through an object to the database.

The update function throws a Syntax Error in cmd.CommandText every time I try to update.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //UPDATE FUNCTION//
    {
            user_management_system user_mgnt = new user_management_system();
            user_mgnt.Username = txt_userName.Text;
            user_mgnt.Password = txt_password.Text;
            user_mgnt.First_name = txt_firstName.Text;
            user_mgnt.Last_name = txt_lastName.Text;
            user_mgnt.Nationality = txt_nationality.Text;
            user_mgnt.Email = txt_email.Text;
            user_mgnt.Age = (txt_age.Text);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE userlogin SET password = ('"+ user_mgnt.Password + "',first_name='" + user_mgnt.First_name + "',last_name='" + user_mgnt.Last_name + "',age='" + user_mgnt.Age +
                          "',nationality='" + user_mgnt.Nationality + "',email='" + user_mgnt.Email + "', WHERE username ='"+ user_mgnt.Username+ "')";
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Data has been successfuly updated");
            displaydata();
```

Comment: If you don't use parameters, you are going to have a bad time.  SQL Injection, formatting errors, etc.

Comment: The very first thing to do is stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL, always. Aside from anything else, it will make it a lot easier to see the SQL you're actually using. (Then there's removing SQL injection attacks.) Next, it looks like you're storing passwords in plain text - I'd very strongly recommend that you stop doing that, too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the query text please follow this form

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra (misplaced) comma before your `WHERE` clause. It should be:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE userlogin SET password = ('"+ user_mgnt.Password + "',first_name='" + user_mgnt.First_name + "',last_name='" + user_mgnt.Last_name + "',age='" + user_mgnt.Age +
                          "',nationality='" + user_mgnt.Nationality + "',email='" + user_mgnt.Email + "' WHERE username ='"+ user_mgnt.Username+ "')";
```

EDIT: And I would agree with those commenting that you should use parameterized SQL, and also avoid storing plain text passwords in the DB.